# Operations lists arcpy

Tags: arcpy

I have a list with 4 raster files and another list with 4 vector files. I want to relate each of the raster file 1 file list 1 vector list.
I try to do and I related file 1 raster to vector file 1,2,3,4. How I can do to relate only 1 with 1, 2 with two and so on?

```
ListaRaster = arcpy.ListRasters("", "img")
1_23165_1997204.img
2_23065_1997197.img
3_23166_1997204.img
4_23066_1997197.img

ListaVector = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("r*")
rec_1.shp
rec_2.shp
rec_3.shp
rec_4.shp

for r in (ListaRaster):
  for v in (ListaVector):
    print ('Raster', r, 'se relaciona con vector', v)
    ('Raster', u'1_23165_1997204.img', 'se relaciona con vector', u'rec_1.shp')
    ('Raster', u'1_23165_1997204.img', 'se relaciona con vector', u'rec_2.shp')
    ('Raster', u'1_23165_1997204.img', 'se relaciona con vector', u'rec_3.shp')
    ('Raster', u'1_23165_1997204.img', 'se relaciona con vector', u'rec_4.shp')
    ('Raster', u'2_23065_1997197.img', 'se relaciona con vector', u'rec_1.shp')
    ('Raster', u'2_23065_1997197.img', 'se relaciona con vector', u'rec_2.shp')
    ('Raster', u'2_23065_1997197.img', 'se relaciona con vector', u'rec_3.shp')
    ('Raster', u'2_23065_1997197.img', 'se relaciona con vector', u'rec_4.shp')
    ('Raster', u'3_23166_1997204.img', 'se relaciona con vector', u'rec_1.shp')
    ('Raster', u'3_23166_1997204.img', 'se relaciona con vector', u'rec_2.shp')
    ('Raster', u'3_23166_1997204.img', 'se relaciona con vector', u'rec_3.shp')
    ('Raster', u'3_23166_1997204.img', 'se relaciona con vector', u'rec_4.shp')
      .......
```

And I want the result to be:

```
('Raster', u'1_23165_1997204.img', 'se relaciona con vector', u'rec_1.shp')
('Raster', u'2_23065_1997197.img', 'se relaciona con vector', u'rec_2.shp')
('Raster', u'3_23166_1997204.img', 'se relaciona con vector', u'rec_3.shp')
('Raster', u'4_23066_1997197.img', 'se relaciona con vector', u'rec_4.shp')
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

you can access list elements with an index.

```
for i in range( min(len(ListaRaster),len(ListaVector)) ): #I use min length to avoid errr if one list is larger than the other one.
     print ('Raster', ListaRaster[i], 'se relaciona con vector', ListaVector[i])
```